Efficient way to send a large amount of text to an element in puppeteer
I know element.type() in puppeteer can be used to send text to the element. But when I test it on a large amount of text, it looks like the characters are typed one by one, which makes sending text very slow.
Alternatively, one can used clipboard to paste the large amount of text to the element. However, on a system, there is just one clipboard, it would interfer with other uses of the clipboard (for example by other processes or by the human user of the computer).
How do you paste text using Puppeteer?
How can I efficiently send a large amount of text to an element without having to use a clipboard?
Do I have to use more fundamental cdp code to achieve this goal?

Please share a [mcve]. In some cases, you can use await page.$eval("input", (el, value) => el.value = value, "your text") (and potentially try to hand-trigger change events as necessary), but it won't work on everything, so this requires a specific site to answer properly.
